# bxslider style configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am trying to setup bxslider, a jquery slider plugin, but their documentation does not tell you how to setup the slider's style like the webpage's examples are setup. I have this code So far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="slider1">
  <li>Slide one content</li>
  <li>Slide two content</li>
  <li>Slide three content</li>
  <li>And so on...</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to add in order to have the buttons and formatting setup like they are on this page: http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Look here - http://bxslider.com/options They have documented the features pretty well

Comment: What does your slider look like now?

Comment: Ok Thanks now I see what I have to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the bx_styles folder and link to the bx_slider stylesheet.

https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/tree/master/bx_styles

Comment: But how/where does the bxSlider make the link reference to this bs_slider.css ???