# Formatting a bxSlider image slider

Tags: jquery, css, formatting, bxslider

I am struggling with how to format a bxSlider image slider (http://www.bxslider.com/).

I am trying to replicate the image slider in this example:
http://bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one

When I follow the instructions that are laid out on the bxSlider site, there is no formatting in the results I get. I figured that I needed to create a link to the CSS file that is included (not sure why that isn't part of their instructions), and that gave me "prev" and "next" button icons, but the slider is extremely long, with a 700px margin in between each image, and exceeds the width of the the browser window.

It seems like part of the JQuery is to attach inline styles with very long widths on the div's, ul's, and li's that it comes across.

I found this, but there is no answer to the question: [bxslider style configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318247/bxslider-style-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Link this bxslider styles and images.

https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/tree/master/bx_styles